# What is the total running time of the following code:

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the total running time of the following code:

I concluded that this code takes O(N log N) times to perform, when the class is being created the loop takes O(N) time to perform, where this for-loop below takes log n time. But I am not completely sure about it, thats why I am asking here.

```
Z z = new Z(N); 
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i = i+2) 
  z.update(i,i+1);
```

Class Z:

```
public class Z
{ 

int[] next, prev;
Z(int N)
{
    prev = new int[N];
    next = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    // put element i in a list of its own
    {
     next[i] = i;
     prev[i] = i;
        }
     }

 int first(int i)
    // return first element of list containing i
 {
     while (i != prev[i]) i = prev[i];
     return i;
 }

 int last(int i)
 // return last element of list containing i
 {
     while (i != next[i]) i = next[i];
     return i;
 }


 void update(int i, int j)
 {
     int f = first(j);
     int l = last(i);
     next[l] = f;
     prev[f] = l;
 }

 boolean query(int i, int j)
 {
 return last(i) == last(j);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The total running time is only `O(N)`.

The constructor's loop has `O(N)` steps.
It creates the `next`/`prev` arrays as `[0, 1, ..., N]`.

`z.update(i,i+1)` takes only `O(1)` time. Since you only call `update()` once for each `i=i` and `j=i+1`,  `first(j)` and `last(i)` will return `j` and `i`, respectively.

It is not possible to analyze the expected complexity of `first()` and `last()` under general conditions, as they could easily contain infinite loops (for instance, if called with `0` when `next=[1,0]`). However, in the example given, they will always skip the `while` loop entirely, as each call to these functions is on an index that has not yet been modified.

Comment: I don't understand. Inside this for-loop we have z.update. Would this not take N/2 time to run? How can it be constant?

for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i = i+2) 
  z.update(i,i+1);

Comment: @leshkari The loop executes `N/2` times, but the `update()` function only takes `O(1)` steps. This gives a total of `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop takes O(N) time. You run it a total of N/2 times and because you ignore the constant this is N. Total runtime O(N^2). There is no logarithm.

Comment: The for loop does not take O(N) time. It could, in some cases, but in the code given it takes O(1).

Comment: To clarify, the loop, as a whole, does take O(N) time. The code inside it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my analysis:

```
Z z = new Z(N); // O(n)
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i = i+2)  // O(n)
 z.update(i,i+1); // O(1)
```

Hence, the total running time will be **O(n)**.

```
int first(int i)
{
    while (i != prev[i]) i = prev[i]; // O(1),  i will always equal prev[i]
                                      // for any input n > 0
    return i;
}

int last(int i)
{
    while (i != next[i]) i = next[i]; // O(1),  i will always equal next[i] 
                                      // for any input n > 0
    return i;
}    

void update(int i, int j)
{
 int f = first(j); // O(1)
 int l = last(i);  // O(1)
 next[l] = f; // O(1)
 prev[f] = l; // O(1)
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is not accurate for `first()` and `last()`. Specifically, the word "always" is incorrect; the values can be changed by `update()`. (It is true for all values with which they are called in this example. Just not "always.")

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but in this example what are the possible values for n? assuming n is an integer, and with the initialization code given for the array, the condition will always evaluate to true for n > 0.

Comment: In this example, yes, but that is not what "always" means. Your answer is the same as mine, so we clearly agree on the given example; I was only suggesting an improvement to your analysis of the functions.

Comment: Yes totally agree with that, but in my answer I considered the whole code as one algorithm including what update() actually does, changing it to modify the array in different way will result in another algorithm that is outside the scope of this analysis.